# Cordova always reinstall app when using `run --device` cli

Tags: cordova

When I using `cordova run android --device`, Cordova always uninstall app before install the new one. I want "update" my app, not "reinstall" it because that would wipe all the data. How can I do that?

Cordova: 6.0.0
Cordova-android: 5.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10157?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20text%20~%20%22uninstall%20app%22).

> Due to the change in CB-9557, the application is ALWAYS uninstalled before being installed.

[The solution](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/251) merged but not in Cordova-android 5.1.0(the last release at this time). So we need update the files in `platform/android/cordova/lib/` manually.